# Need more information on these mechanical aspects of programming

Tags: visual-studio, physics

I recently noticed that in fuel stations when the petrol attendant gives out petrol through the pumps the computers inside the filling station already get to know the amount that has been filled in.

I would like to know:

- What type of programming and any additional devices (if any) are used and if there is a special name given for this kind of programming and if it can be done through Visual Basic or I need to get another programming software to do it.
- Also I think that to make such programs there will be a need to get data from a tangible source (such as the fuel pump and how much it has filled) (and even giving instructions to robotic arms and the like). So I would like to know if there is a converter of some sort in the middle to allow connection or must the program be made to suite the existing equipment.
- In the case of the robotic arm what is needed, in terms of, programming languages that these commands can be done on or for the fuel pump "How the computer will read the information from the pumps"

I thought that most programs like point of sale programs and other accounting program take values from us and return us values, the result and the calculations seem completely virtual but that programming where we can make mechanical things such as robotic arms and fuel pumps work (physically) to our commands and/or return values based on what they just did is very alien to me.

If there is a relevant book you know or websites please inform me about it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on-topic here. A simple approach is detecting how long the button has been pressed, a harder approach is using some kind of meter where the fuel passes through that detects how fast the fuel passes through it over time. Then it's just an electronic circuit that makes it into useful valuse, and these can be passed over any interface towards the attendant.

Comment: @TomWijsman Any interface? can it also be done using Visual Studio. But what I dont get is how the program will detect the signals from the other devices. Please tell me if you can find a book looking into this

Comment: This is language agnostic, it doesn't matter what you use as long as it is able to communicate with the lower level stuff. It's basically reading out COM or I/O ports in one or another way, but that would depend on the language and interface (I/O or port interface, not the IDE) you are using...

Comment: This kind of system, wherein a dedicated computer controls something (like a mechanical pump), performs a fixed task with very little flexibility, and does nothing else, is called an **embedded system**. Many books have been written on the subject, many web pages written, many courses taught.

Comment: @TomWijsman Thanks for that piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* write such a program in Visual Basic (I'm embarrassed to admit that I have written code to control something similar to a robotic arm in Visual Basic).

Take the example of the gas pump. Somewhere in the pump is a digital flow meter with some kind of hardware interface. I did a google search ("flow meter USB") and found some that communicate with USB, but I imagine a decent amount are still available with RS-232 connectors (this was the common serial port on the back of computers before USB).

Most likely the vendor will provide some sort of API for accessing the information on the device. If you are lucky, it will be something that is easy to use in Visual Basic. If you are unlucky, it will be a C API, and you will have to write a small wrapper library to use unmanaged code that you can then use in Visual Basic.

In the example of the robot arm, you might have a USB interface, an RS-232 interface, or something stranger. I've had something built by a grad student that was controlled via a special TTL board in the computer (lots of individual wires were coming out of the back of the computer). The problem is no different, structurally. You write a small wrapper library that deals with the unmanaged code, then you use that wrapper library in Visual Basic.

If you are lucky, and there's always a dotNet (or COM+) API for the devices you are interested in working with, you could do quite a bit only knowing Visual Basic. If no such API is available, and you want to tackle the problem on your own, you'll probably have to learn a little bit of C and even assembly (The most recent book I own on the subject, "Embedded Systems Programming in C and Assembly," still has a 3.5" disk in the front cover. You'll probably want something a little more recent). A google search for "embedded systems visual basic" actually turned up some interesting references. Similarly, "visual basic robots" returned several interesting references.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any specific references I could recommend. Most embedded systems books that I've encountered were for C and/or assembly. Most of those assumed a Unix environment (QNX). You might still find code written in some flavor of Basic, but using Basic's peek and poke commands for memory access. This is only of limited value. Visual Basic doesn't have peek and poke, and you'd probably want an API that's a bit higher level than that anyway.